# There is no prompt to select USB device using navigator.usb.requestDevice() on Zebra Enterprise Browser

Tags: usb, zebra-printers, webusb

I am trying to use Web USB API to communicate with USB relay. The web page is running on Zebra device. It is working fine in Chromium. I am getting a prompt to select USB device.

device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: config.VENDOR_ID, productId: config.PRODUCT_ID }] });

The Zebra device comes with Enterprise Browser. It is similar to Chromium. But I do not get the prompt to select USB device when running the same web page in Enterprise Browser.

Does anyone know how to get this working in the Enterprise Browser?

Or is there any way that navigator.usb.requestDevice() returns the device without user's action?

Thank you.

Comment: *navigator.usb* is an experimental technology. Is it implemented by the Zebra browser?

Comment: Thank you so much. Will reach out to Zebra's support channels.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reaching out to Zebra's support channels with questions about their browser. Even if it is based on Chromium it may not include or have disabled components of the WebUSB implementation.

The [WebUsbAllowDevicesForUrls](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#WebUsbAllowDevicesForUrls) enterprise policy allows an administrator to pre-grant permission for a site to access USB devices but that depends on the browser having the complete WebUSB *and* enterprise policy engine from the upstream Chromium project so there's no guarantee that it will work without reaching out to Zebra.

Zebra Enterprise Browser may be based on Android WebView instead of Chromium. While Android WebView is itself based on Chromium it doesn't include the code necessary to support the WebUSB API. Adding support for WebUSB to Android WebView is tracked by Chromium's [issue 933055](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933055).

Comment: Thank you so much. Will reach out to Zebra's support channels.